# What is location of django Built-in tags and filters?

Tags: python, django

What is location of django Built-in tags and filters? I cant find anywhere... I need it to format datetime so then i can send right formt in JSON by AJAX response.. Or maybe you can suggest me another way to do that...

What i want to do it's import function which determinate filter... and use it to format my datetime in JSON.

Look.. i have...

```
media_items = Media.objects.filter(blablabla=blablabla)
```

than i do

```
data = serializers.serialize('json', media_items, fields=('name','duration','on_air'))
```

How can I do so in `data`(what is JSON) i have right date format? What is the simplest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean location? Do you mean where in Django's code does it live? If so, the default filters live in [`django.template.defaultfilters`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/defaultfilters.py).

If you're wanting to do date formatting in a view, then use [`dateformat`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/dateformat.py).

You can see an example of how to use `dateformat` in the code for the `time` filter, visible [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L716).

Comment: Yes.. i meant where it lives.. thanks a lot.. and about you example as well!